# C++ Erase(0,1); in string, removing all instances of character in file

Tags: c++, file, erase

I have a program that checks for "*@*" in the '*isMemLoc()*' function, and if it finds one it should remove it. (this symbol will always be the first character on the line, hence the *erase(0,1)* call

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


bool replace(std::string& str, const std::string& from, const std::string& to) {
    size_t start_pos = str.find(from);
    if(start_pos == std::string::npos)
        return false;
    str.replace(start_pos, from.length(), to);
    return true;
}

bool isComment(string line){
    string comment = "/";
    if(line.find(comment) != string::npos){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

bool isMemLoc(string line){
    string symbol = "@";
    if(line.find(symbol) != string::npos){
        cout << "CONSTANT FOUND" << endl;
        //ConvertToBinary(atoi(line.c_str));
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}



 int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
    string outLine = "test output";
    string file1 = argv[1];
    cout << "before: " << file1 << endl;
    replace(file1, "asm", "hack");
    cout << "after: " << file1 << endl;

    //input
    //WHILE READ LINE()
    ifstream infile(argv[1]);
    string tempLine;

    ofstream outfile(file1.c_str());

    while (getline(infile, tempLine)){
        if(isComment(tempLine))
            continue;
        if(isMemLoc(tempLine)){
            tempLine.erase(0);
            cout << tempLine << endl;
            outfile << tempLine << std::endl;
            continue;
        }

        //print to terminal and pass to file
        cout << tempLine << endl;   
        outfile << tempLine << std::endl;
    }

    outfile.close();
}
```

However, when it finds this character, my program is also deleting all of the lines where this value is found eg:

```
1
2
3
13 
@12
@12
@13
2
```

turns into

```
1
2
3
13 
2
```

This is undesired. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You sure the lines aren't getting filtered out by `isComment()`? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sure barry I'll edit it now

Comment: Are you sure it's not wrong in the `isMemLoc` or `isComment` functions? Have you tried to step through the code, line by line, in a debugger?

Comment: Hey Joachim, I have tried but I cannot find the problem

Comment: I have added the functions to make the code easier to understand

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/225b0691d1a8f05b)

Comment: Sorry Barry, I have added the main function, it should compile now

Comment: Just a few small but unrelated notes on your code: First of all pass the strings by constant reference to the functions, i.e. they should take a `const std::string&` as argument. Secondly, you don't need the temporary strings for the characters you search for, the [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) function have an overload for characters, so you can just do `line.find('@')`. Thirdly, you don't need the `if`, you can return the condition directly, e.g. `return line.find('&') != std::string::npos;`

Comment: Thanks Joachim, I'm still a C++ newbie

Comment: @BarneyChambers The issue isn't that it doesn't compile - I ran your code and it does exactly what you say it should be doing.

Comment: @BarneyChambers Oh, you changed it to `erase(0)`... this is why it's important to reproduce your examples exactly!

Comment: Oh and a fourth note, after the changes suggested in my previous comment, if you mark the functions as `inline` the compiler might be able to optimize away the calls completely. So the `isMemLoc` function could look like `inline bool isMemLoc(const string& line) { return line.find('@') != string::npos; }`

Comment: This question is essentially an exercise in assisted manual reading. Combined with the verbose presentation that makes no effort to isolate the problem and restrict itself to a minimal test case and the obscure title, I'm voting to close this for having no future value.

Comment: Congratulations Kerrek, well done, kudos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you had this in your question (which was right):

```
tempLine.erase(0, 1);
```

Then, you changed the code to this (I suppose it's the original one):

```
tempLine.erase(0);
```

See [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) and you'll find out that the `count` parameter is defaulted to `std::string::npos` - erases characters till end.

Comment: Hey LogicStuff, this helps a little bit as tempLine.erase(0) removes the number 13 before the @ symbol. What should I use instead of npos?

Comment: @Barney Chambers Really **before**?

Comment: _hence the `erase(0,1)`call_ - I can't see any. You have `tempLine.erase(0)` instead. The first version in the answer is right - I don't know why you don't get it.